# What is the equivalent of the SumIf function in R

Tags: r

I am new to R and this site, but I searched and didn't find the answer I was looking for.

If I have the following data set "total":

```
names <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "b", "c", "d")
x <- cbind(x1 = 3, x2 = c(3:10))
total <- data.frame(names, x)
total

  names x1 x2
1     a  3  3
2     b  3  4
3     c  3  5
4     d  3  6
5     a  3  7
6     b  3  8
7     c  3  9
8     d  3  10
```

How can I create a new data set that works like the SumIf Excel function with just unique rows?

The answer should be a new data set "summary" that is 4 x 3.

```
names <- unique(names)
summary <- data.frame(names)
summary$Sumx1 <- ?????
summary$Sumx2 <- ?????
summary

 names Sumx1 Sumx2
1  a     6    10
2  b     6    12
3  c     6    14
4  d     6    16
```

Answer (score 12):

In base R:

```
aggregate(. ~ names, data=total, sum)
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use `ddply` from the `plyr` package:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(total, .(names), summarise, Sumx1 = sum(x1), Sumx2 = sum(x2))

  names Sumx1 Sumx2
1     a     6    10
2     b     6    12
3     c     6    14
4     d     6    16
```

You can also use `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(total)
DT[ , lapply(.SD, sum), by = "names"]

   names x1 x2
1:     a  6 10
2:     b  6 12
3:     c  6 14
4:     d  6 16
```

With the new `dplyr` package, you can do:

```
library(dplyr)
total %>%
  group_by(names) %>%
  summarise(Sumx1 = sum(x1), Sumx2 = sum(x2))

  names Sumx1 Sumx2
1     d     6    16
2     c     6    14
3     b     6    12
4     a     6    10
```

Comment: What if I have more than the required columns in my DT? Could it be done in a single line of code without making a subset DT?

Comment: @AbhishekSingh The other columns are ignored in `summarise` unless you specify operations for them.