# Code in R to sum only part of a column (group defined by rows)

Tags: r

I have a table of the form:

```
headers   c1.r1.s1  c1.r1.s2  c1.r2.s1  c1.r2.s2  c2.r1.s1
c1.r1.s1     34       76         86        21        45
c1.r1.s2     85       34         47        35        97
c1.r2.s1     12       25         64        47        23
c1.r2.s1     87       54         78        31        25
c2.r1.s1     34       67         49        10        72
```

where the headers of columns (and rows) represent a combination of country (1 and 2), region (1 and 2) and sector (1 and 2). Let's name the first column "headers" for convenience.

I would like to add two additional rows and columns with partial sums, defined by the headers.

For the first extra row and column, I would like to add the values defined by the same region in the same country (within a certain column and row):

```
headers   c1.r1.s1  c1.r1.s2  c1.r2.s1  c1.r2.s2  c2.r1.s1   sum1r
c1.r1.s1   **34**   **76**       86        21        45     **110**
c1.r1.s2   **85**   **44**       47        35        97     **129**
c1.r2.s1     12       25       **64**    **47**      23     **111**
c1.r2.s1     87       54       **78**    **31**      25     **109**
c2.r1.s1     34       67         49        10      **72**   **72**
sum1c     **119**  **120**    **142**    **78**    **72**
```

For the second extra column and row, I want something similar but adding the values of the same country (as defined in the header):

```
headers   c1.r1.s1  c1.r1.s2  c1.r2.s1  c1.r2.s2  c2.r1.s1   sum1r     sum2r
c1.r1.s1   **34**   **76**     **86**    **21**      45       110     **217**
c1.r1.s2   **85**   **44**     **47**    **35**      97       129     **211**
c1.r2.s1   **12**   **25**     **64**    **47**      23       111     **148**
c1.r2.s1   **87**   **54**     **78**    **31**      25       109     **250**
c2.r1.s1     34       67         49        10      **72**     72      **72**
sum1c       119      120        142        78        72   
sum2c     **218**  **199**    **275**   **144**    **72**
```

My main problem is that I have many countries, regions and sectors; and I'm unable to make my head around how to code "sum the values of this column if the header of the row is the same to this extent".

I'm very sorry if this has been already addressed. I looked around and couldn't find a solution, but if someone can give me any hint I would be incredibly thankful.

*EDIT*

I found this, which looks pretty much like a solution to my problem, although I don't need a separate matrix with the results, and the sums are slightly different:

[R partial sum of rows/columns of a matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37149318/r-partial-sum-of-rows-columns-of-a-matrix)

I'm not that familiar with R (obviously), so I'm wondering if this can be modified to fit my problem.

I understand the structure of the data is not ideal, but I need to keep it as it is since it reflects inter-industry flows.

Comment: While it's certainly possible to do the type of calculation you are looking to do, it is made a lot more difficult based on the structure of your data.  I would suggest trying to reformat your data as [Tidy Data](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html) format.  General principle is that each column is one variable, each row is one observation.  Your columns (and rows) each represent multiple variables stuck together.  Once there, [see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21607464/what-is-the-equivalent-of-the-sumif-function-in-r) for more info.

Comment: Thanks you for your comment. It is true that the data structure is complicated, but I need it like this so I can perform other calculations later on. I edited my original post to add some info about it.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking your dataframe is inflatet, since the column- and rownames contain the same information, wich doesnt help you. try to make it more tidy, in a way that every coulmn contains one type of information, like country or region. (it wouldnt matter if two different countrys have the same region code like "r1", because R can handle this easy.

To demonstrate what i mean i created this short example with Continents and their countrys:

```
df<-cbind(na.exclude(countrycode::codelist[,c(2,18)]),
          rnorm(length(na.exclude(countrycode::codelist[,c(2,18)]))),
          dnorm(length(na.exclude(countrycode::codelist[,c(2,18)]))))
colnames(df)<-c("continent","region", "value", "value2")


#
> head(df)
  continent         region     value     value2
1      Asia    Afghanistan 0.4148095 0.05399097
2    Europe  Åland Islands 0.3974413 0.05399097
3    Europe        Albania 0.4148095 0.05399097
4    Africa        Algeria 0.3974413 0.05399097
5   Oceania American Samoa 0.4148095 0.05399097
6    Europe        Andorra 0.3974413 0.0539909
```

following up we use the dplyr package with the group function to make your calculations:

```
library(dplyr)

df2<-df %>% 
group_by(continent) %>% mutate(continent.val.sums= sum(value, value2))

> head(df2)
# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   continent [4]
  continent region         value value2 continent.val.sums
  <chr>     <chr>          <dbl>  <dbl>              <dbl>
1 Asia      Afghanistan    0.415 0.0540               23.1
2 Europe    Åland Islands  0.397 0.0540               23.4
3 Europe    Albania        0.415 0.0540               23.4
4 Africa    Algeria        0.397 0.0540               26.7
5 Oceania   American Samoa 0.415 0.0540               11.9
6 Europe    Andorra        0.397 0.0540               23.4
```

there are many ways and functions to do these types of calculations group and mutate being only one.

```
df3<-df2 %>%  group_by(region) %>% mutate(region.val.sums= sum(value2))


> head(df3)
# A tibble: 6 x 6
# Groups:   region [6]
  continent region         value value2 continent.val.sums region.val.sums
  <chr>     <chr>          <dbl>  <dbl>              <dbl>           <dbl>
1 Asia      Afghanistan    0.415 0.0540               23.1          0.0540
2 Europe    Åland Islands  0.397 0.0540               23.4          0.0540
3 Europe    Albania        0.415 0.0540               23.4          0.0540
4 Africa    Algeria        0.397 0.0540               26.7          0.0540
5 Oceania   American Samoa 0.415 0.0540               11.9          0.0540
6 Europe    Andorra        0.397 0.0540               23.4          0.0540
```

this sum of course makes no sense because sum of value2 per region equals the value since theres only one distinct region. But its only to demonstrate the principle , you can make other groups and subgroups, or use other functions like mean() or summarise() summarize(), etc

Comment: Thank you very much. I edited my question so it is a bit more informative on why the data has that structure. The main problem with your approach is that I would lose the interconnection between rows and columns (as originally defined) , a key feature that I need to keep for my analysis.

Comment: I begin to understand what you are aiming for,  the problem with that is, that matrizes and tables work in very different ways, mixing them together would break things certanly. If you want to calculate for example, lets say trade deficits, doing it by matrix calculation is a good way, but you have to understand that your output always has to be a new  m \times n-Matrix with the deficites between each country (where theres a diagonal 0- line in the middle ).  This is not a bad thing, because input and output stays separate and readable for men and machine.

Comment: On the other hand; using table calculation( as i supposed in my answer) gives you the advantage, that you are free to add as many new columns as you wish, without breaking things, they can even contain different types of data, factors, and summarys. It has the advantage that everything stays in one big data.frame  , the disadvantage is due its ever growing size,  it can get very big and unclear (if you have lets say 100+ columns times 100.000+ rows)  also due to the size calculation speed slows down. Then you consider  subsetting your table,  to make it more comprehensible.